# Laravel: check relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Please bear with me, i'm bad at explaining things and i don't think the title suits my problem.

I have a User model and a Course model.
These models have a manytomany relationship.

There currently are 4 Courses, but the User only has a relationship with 2 of them (lets say Course 1 and 3).

On a certain page i'd like to output all Courses, and highlight the Courses the User has a relationship with, so it can view the Course. So, Course 1 and 3 will be highlighted, while Course 2 and 4 will be faded.

User model:

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
}
```

Course Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

The Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $member = $this->auth->user();
    $courses = $this->courserepository->getAllCourses(); // Course 1,2,3,4
    $member_courses = $member->courses; // Course 1,3

    // Logic to filter courses which are in a relationship with the User

    return view('member.course.index', compact('member', 'courses'));
}
```

I wish i had some more code, but i have deleted most of it since it was not working as suspected.. I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In controller replace:

```
$member = $this->auth->user()->with('courses');
```

then in view:

```
<ul>
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <li@if(in_array($course['id'], array_column($member['courses'], 'id'))){{' class="highlighted"'}}@endif>
        {{$course->name}}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```